# jQuery toggleClass with single select on - on both left click and right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple images in a div. On click of the image, it should toggle something like select and de-select. At a time only one img can be selected or none. I used the code below:

```
function imageSelect(img) {
    $("#" + img.id).toggleClass("htmlView_img_select_toggle");
    $('#snapshotsRpt > img').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        $('.htmlView_img_select_toggle').removeClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
        $(this).addClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
    });
};
```

But at the end of it, at least one will remain selected. I don't want that. I should still be able to de-select image by clicking again but with single select functionality.

The HTML code is:

```
            htmlBody+='<div id="snapshotsRpt">';

        if (imgArray && imgArray.length>0){
            for (var i=0;i<imgArray.length;i++){
                htmlBody+='<img id="'+'Img'+i+'" src="'+imgArray[i].src+'" style="cursor: pointer; height:75%; width: 75%; display: block; margin: 10px; text-align: center;" class="" onclick="imageSelect(this);" oncontextmenu="rightClickMenu(this);"></img>';  
            }   
        } 

        htmlBody+='</div><div id="noScreenshot"></div>';
```

I am newbie to jquery. Please help!

Comment: share your html also

Comment: if you are dynamically creating div and image elements, you should be using `on()` method to bind the click event handlers.

Comment: @Stu you can use following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/dsk6pkrd/) as reference.

Comment: Even this one is working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation like

```js
function loadimgs() {
  var htmlBody = '',
    imgArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    imgArray.push({
      src: '//placehold.it/100?text=' + (i + 1)
    })
  }

  htmlBody += '<div id="snapshotsRpt">';

  if (imgArray && imgArray.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
      htmlBody += '<img id="' + 'Img' + i + '" src="' + imgArray[i].src + '" style="cursor: pointer; height:75%; width: 75%; display: block; margin: 10px; text-align: center;" class="" oncontextmenu="rightClickMenu(this);"></img>';
    }
  }

  htmlBody += '</div><div id="noScreenshot"></div>';
  $('body').append(htmlBody);
}

//on dom ready
$(document).on('click', '#snapshotsRpt img', function() {
  console.log('a')
  $('#snapshotsRpt img.htmlView_img_select_toggle').not(this).removeClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
  $(this).toggleClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
});
```

```css
.htmlView_img_select_toggle {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="loadimgs()">Load</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help :)