# Use Jquery for single select with mouse click and multiselect with CTRL + Click on the image inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having a situation here! 
I have multiple images in a div. On click of the image, it should toggle something like select and de-select but, at a time only one image should be selected on Click event or none.

Now, when using CTRL+Click, I should be able to select/toggle other images also, something like multi-select.

Following is my code for single-select

[jQuery toggleClass with single select on - on both left click and right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073853/jquery-toggleclass-with-single-select-on-on-both-left-click-and-right-click)

```
    $(document).on('click', '#snapshotsRpt img', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    $('#snapshotsRpt img.htmlView_img_select_toggle').not(this).removeClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
    $(this).toggleClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
});

$(document).on('mousedown', '#snapshotsRpt img', function(e){
    if(e.which == 3){
        e.preventDefault;
        $('#snapshotsRpt img.htmlView_img_select_toggle').removeClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
        $(this).addClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
    }
});
```

This is what I tried doing for ctrl-click but something is not quite right.

```
    $(document).on('click', '#snapshotsRpt img', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  // To detect ctrl + click
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    //alert("need to select multiple");
    $(this).toggleClass('htmlView_img_select_toggle');
  }
});
```

Any direction will be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the demo which will hek

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".selectOption").click(function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        } else {
            if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                $(".selectOption").removeClass("selected");

            } else {
                $(".selectOption").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            }

        }
    });
});
```

```css
.selectOption{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:red;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

.selected{
 background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectOption"></div>
<div class="selectOption"></div>
<div class="selectOption"></div>
<div class="selectOption"></div>
<div class="selectOption"></div>
```

Comment: This works well for my case. Thanks a lot! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

May be this is not what you are expecting. But this could do the trick. `**jQueryUI**` has an interaction called `**Selectable**`

So the structure should be,

```
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 80px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  });
```

**A working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2yskob2/)**